# Download Heroku roll back and push changes

Tags: git, heroku, download, push, rollback

I inadvertently made a bad update on my Heroky app and rolled back to another stable release. Now I'm trying to download this stable release on my hard drive and I thought I had it with the command `git checkout release`. However I made a change on my hard drive and now I can't push with the normal commands :

```
$ git add .
$ git commit -am "make it better"
$ git push heroku master
```

What is the normal way to download an anterior release and to push it again after changes?

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by can't push? What error are you getting?